# Python printing values of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

In Python, I know you print the values of a key in a dictionary by doing `variable.values()`. But what if I wanted to print a value of a particular value?

For an example:

```
pets = {'Dog': ['Poodle', 'Boxer', 'Terrier'], 'Cat': ['Sphynx', 'Ragdoll', 'Birman']}
```

I want to specifically choose a particular breed of animal. For instance, I just want to print `Boxer`.

You could do something like:

```
animal = list(pets.values())[0]
breed = list(animal.values())[1]
print(breed)
```

This will give you `Boxer`. However, I was curious if I can do this in a single line of code like printing a value of a value.

I've tried:

```
breed = list(list(pets.values()))[0][1]
```

but it tells me that the string index is out of range.

Comment: The given dictonary `pets`, is not valid syntax fix that first.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the `.values()` of a dictionary... You lose all the efficiency. Use keys for example: `pets['Dog']`.

Comment: @Poojan Whoops, thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(list(pets.values()))
```

output:

```
[['Poodle', 'Boxer', 'Terrier'], ['Sphynx', 'Ragdoll', 'Birman']]
```

- As you can see its a list of list. Now each item is list you can access by indexing.

```
breed = list(pets.values())[0][1]
```

- this will give you desired result.

Comment: Oh right. I forgot that dictionaries don't always list the stuff in order, hence why you can't index things.

Answer (score 0):

your data structure is a dict with "sets" as values.
sets are not subscriptable and converting in a list doesn't keep the order

```
>>> list(pets['Dog'])
['Boxer', 'Poodle', 'Terrier']
```

the question is then .... what do you really need?

If you need to access to breed you could/should use lists or tuples instead of sets

Answer (score -1):

it seems strange about how you are using dict, I assume in your case you should use list instead

```
pets = {'Animal': {'Dog': ['Poodle', 'Boxer', 'Terrier'], 'Cat': ['Sphynx', 'Ragdoll', 'Birman']}}
```

if you want a specific breed to print, then you might need an additional key for that to gain benefits of using dict

```
pets = {'Animal': {'Dog': {1:'Poodle', 2:'Boxer', 3:'Terrier'}, 'Cat': ['Sphynx', 'Ragdoll', 'Birman']}}
```

then you can get boxer with

```
pets['Animal']['Dog'][2]
```

Comment: You completly changed the structure of dict provided by OP.

Answer (score -1):

The way you are defining this dictionary creates a syntax error:

```
>>> pets = {'Animal': 'Dog':{'Poodle','Boxer','Terrier'}, 'Cat':{'Sphynx','Ragdoll','Birman'}}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pets = {'Animal': 'Dog':{'Poodle','Boxer','Terrier'}, 'Cat':{'Sphynx','Ragdoll','Birman'}}
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I created a similar dictionary (this time a dictionary of species as key and breeds as values), and show how you can index this new dictionary:

```
>>> pets = {'Dog':('Poodle','Boxer','Terrier'), 'Cat':('Sphynx','Ragdoll','Birman')}
>>> pets['Dog'][1]
'Boxer'
>>>
```

Comment: You changed the structure of given dict. Let OP first validate the input.

Comment: Good catch, @Poojan. I realized right after posting and will correct.